# Macro_Change date format to DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: .net

I would like to change date format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MMM-YYYY in particular column of excel. I’m not able to change it....I’ve tried it with “Text To Column” functionality but further coding has impact of “Text to column functionality”. Please suggest appropriate macro code for it. Thanks!

Comment: So, create custom number format for this column: right-click -> Format Cells -> Number tab -> Custom. In the "Type" text field enter your format.

Comment: Thank you Johny for your response, unfortunately it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me;

```
Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@"
```